# "Add to Cart" in Lightbox – Shopify

Tags: ajax, shopify

Here's the URL to my store: http://nibblesofnirvana.myshopify.com

(PASSWORD IS nibblesofnirvana)

What I want to do is present people with two options when they click "add to cart." If you get to "add to cart" on the website now, you'll see that I already have a lightbox that comes up.

I want one option that points to the regular checkout page, then another option that points to a new checkout page that I haven't made yet.

But I haven't been able to get the shopping cart to work. I'd like "BUY NOW" to add the item the person is viewing to the cart, and the other option I display simply link to another page.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the Ajax API, but shopify's documentation hasn't proven to be all that helpful... would be very helpful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

click `add to cart` --> pop up small window of [highslide js](http://highslide.com/) and in this popup, you can place your two options.. am i following your thought?

Comment: Well, I already have the lightbox working. When you click "add to cart", it opens up a colorbox.

The problem is, within the lightbox, I'm having problems getting the original item to add to the actual cart. I'd like to keep the "add to cart" functionality, just move it to the lightbox so I can display two different options.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: this is js issue. do this: (pseudo)
``<li onclick="popup(this.item)"></li>`` and in your popup() you will add the item value to lightbox targeting some ``id`` element in lightbox.. am i okay? :D

Comment: Hmm... I think we're close to on the same page here. 

Did you get a chance to visit the site I linked in my question? If you click an item then click "add to cart", you can see the lightbox I have working.

But then clicking BUY NOW doesn't put the product in the cart, which is what I want. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Password is nibblesofnirvana

Comment: still not solved? what framework r u using? if any mvc, then show me your view and url please